# How to load multiple css files before the closing head tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, stylesheet

I was wondering how to make this code work for 2 css files. We use the code below in functions.php to load in our own css just before the closing head tag, but we want to load in a second css just before the closing head tag. How do we make this code work for 2 css files?

```
function register_my_custom_styles() {
wp_register_style("boldbase-styles", "//boldbase.nl/l/wp-content/uploads/bb-style.css");
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "register_my_custom_styles");

function styles_to_go_after_oxygen() {
wp_print_styles("boldbase-styles");
}
add_action("wp_head", "styles_to_go_after_oxygen", 1000000 );
```

Comment: Look at the source code of the plugin you are using that is messing with you... find out where they are enqueuing their scripts. set a higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

You can load multiple CSS using only `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

```
function load_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style ("first style", "url/first-style.css", array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_style ("second style", "url/second-style.css", array(), null);
  wp_enqueue_style ("third style", "url/third-style.css", array(), null);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles_scripts', 99999);
```

The stylesheets will be placed in the same order inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: The problem is that the plugin we're using has his own css file that loads in just before the closing head tag. So we can't get our own css files past that one with this method unfortunately

Comment: I got it. So, using the number in this case didn't work for you?

Comment: No that was not enough to push it all the way below, before the closing head tag :(

Comment: I don't know what plugin you used, but I think you could try to find out how it is putting this style on the head. Then it would be easy to know how to override the order.